# About group actions and orbits that are singletons.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions

Let me start with some definitions and remarks.

I write $.$ to denote a group action of the group $G$ on the set $X$

$O(x) = \{g.x|g \in G\}$ (known as the orbit of $x$)

$X_G = \{x \in X|\forall g \in G: g.x = x\}$

I want to prove that $$\bigcup_{x \in X, |O(x)|=1} O(x) = X_G$$ (if someone knows how to format this better, feel free to comment or edit)

I don't even know whether the statement itself is true (I came up with it myself) but here is my attempt. Can someone verify whether this is correct?

**Proof**

$\subset$

Let $y \in \bigcup_{x \in X, |O(x)|=1} O(x)$. Then, there is an $x \in X$ such that $y \in O(x)$ and $|O(x)| = 1$. Since $x \in O(x)$, it follows that $x = y$. Hence, $O(x) = \{x\} $ and therefore, we know, by definition of $O(x)$ that for all $g \in G$ we have that $g.x = x$. Hence, $x \in X_G$ and thus $y \in X_G$

$\supset$

Let $y \in X_G$. Then, for all $g \in G$ we have g.y = y. Therefore, $O(y) = \{y\}$. And thus $|O(y)| = 1$. Hence, $y \in \bigcup_{x \in X, |O(x)|=1} O(x) \quad \triangle$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: The proof, and thus the statement are correct.

Comment: That's correct, nice job.  Another way: if $x \in X$, then $O(x) = \{x\}$  if and only if $|O(x)| = 1$ if and only if $x \in X_G$.  So $$X_G = \bigcup\limits_{x \in X_G} \{x\} = \bigcup\limits_{x \in X, |O(x)| = 1} \{x\} = \bigcup\limits_{x \in X, |O(x)|=1} O(x)$$